# It is possible to add text fields, labels or anything else in a running activity on a real/emulated Android device?

Tags: android, shell, sdk, adb

I'm not sure, but can I use `adb shell commands` from the Android sdk to install a new package in an existing and running app in order to add new components in the activity just coding from terminal ?

I suppose something like :

```
adb shell am -n com.example.myapp
ant <app path>
cd <sdk platform-tools folder>
adb shell pm install <created apk path>
adb shell am -n com.example.myapp.new_activity
```

Comment: adb doesn't have any command that does anything similar to what you're looking for.

Comment: ok I expected it but i wanted to be sure, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the full list of commands supported by `adb` at https://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html